# Can I deploy via Git to Rackspace Cloud Sites?

Tags: git, rackspace, rackspace-cloud-sites

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to deploy to Rackspace Cloud Sites via Git-push?

I contacted the Rackspace support and all they can tell me is that I might be able to as long as I don't need root access. Is that something that's possible?

I can't seem to find anything on Google, but I thought I would at least double check, as i'm only familiar with pushing to GitHub & Heroku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rackspace cloud sites doesn't allow git upload, only FTP upload is allowed.

Comment: Correct. (SFTP is supported too) The other answers are confusing Cloud Sites and Cloud Servers.

If you want to push via Git to a PaaS, you could try something like Appharbor.

Comment: I looked into Appharbor and it seems to only do .net apps. Has anyone used www.deployhq.com ? That is the only deploy specific PaaS I can find on Google. Any others I should check out?

Comment: You could make it part of your post-recieve hook in git to upload via SFTP then. Allowing you to "deploy via git push". I use this method for my blog. http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-3.html

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have git installed on your instance.

**On the server** create a repo for a server with "--bare"

```
[server:~/]$ mkdir app.git
[server:~/]$ cd app.git
[server:~/app.git]$ git init --bare
```

**On the client** clone, commit, and push:

```
[client:~/]$ git clone ssh://<username>@<servername>/~/app.git app
[client:~/]$ cd app
[client:~/app]$ touch readme.rst
[client:~/app]$ git add readme.rst
[client:~/app]$ git commit -am"Initial commit" 
[client:~/app]$ git push origin master
```

Now your code has been pushed to the server. What you can do from here is up to you.

Additional note: git is a distributed version control system, which means there is little difference between a "client" and a "server". In this case, there is no extra service running on your server, you only need ssh access, git does the rest.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have deleted my answer to remove the noise.

Comment: That was unnecessary, it was a fine answer.

Comment: ... a fine answer for a Cloud *Server*, not a Cloud *Site* as specified in the OP's question.